# Why is the closure called when using HashMap's or_insert?

Tags: hashmap, rust

I am beginning with Rust and have troubles understanding how the following snippet of code outputs what it does. Surely the closure in `or_insert` method should not be called when the entry exists or am I completely missing something?

```
struct Cacher {
    result: HashMap<u32, u32>,
}

impl Cacher {
    fn new() -> Cacher {
        Cacher{
            result: HashMap::new()
        }
    }

    fn result(&mut self, arg: u32) -> u32 {
        match self.result.get(&arg) {
            Some(v) => println!("I have value {} for {}", v, arg),
            None => println!("No value for {}", arg)
        }
        let closure = |x| {
            println!("Doing complicated stuff.....");
            thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(2));
            x + 42
        };
        let v = self.result.entry(arg).or_insert((closure)(arg));
        *v
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut business_logic = Cacher::new();
    business_logic.result(10);
    business_logic.result(10);
}
```

Output:

```
No value for 10
Doing complicated stuff.....
I have value 52 for 10
Doing complicated stuff.....
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The closure is called *because you called it*:

```
(closure)(arg)
```

[`hash_map::Entry::or_insert`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/hash_map/enum.Entry.html#method.or_insert) doesn't accept a closure:

> ```
> pub fn or_insert(self, default: V) -> &'a mut V
> ```
>
> Ensures a value is in the entry by inserting the default if empty, and
>   returns a mutable reference to the value in the entry.

[`hash_map::Entry::or_insert_with`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/hash_map/enum.Entry.html#method.or_insert_with) does:

> ```
> pub fn or_insert_with<F: FnOnce() -> V>(self, default: F) -> &'a mut V
> ```
>
> Ensures a value is in the entry by inserting the result of the default
>   function if empty, and returns a mutable reference to the value in the
>   entry.

Applied to your code:

```
fn result(&mut self, arg: u32) -> u32 {
    match self.result.get(&arg) {
        Some(v) => println!("I have value {} for {}", v, arg),
        None => println!("No value for {}", arg),
    }
    *self.result.entry(arg).or_insert_with(|| {
        println!("Doing complicated stuff.....");
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(2));
        arg + 42
    })
}
```